# Create custom permalinks to show Custom Post Type's relationship?

Tags: php, permalinks, url-rewriting, urls, rewrite-rules

I'm creating a WordPress site that has 3 custom post types registered: `course`, `chapter`, and `lesson`.

All of these post types are inter-connected and share a relationship using custom fields. For example, the `chapter` has a custom field that stores the `course` post object in which it belongs to. Same goes for the `lesson` and the `chapter` it belongs to.

My permalink settings are using the: `%category%/%postname%/` structure, in which display the post's URL like so:

`www.domainname.com/custom-post-type-name/post-name`

What i'm trying to accomplish is to create a custom permalink structure that shows the relationship between these 3 post types in the URL. Example below:

When user is on course:
`www.domainname.com/course`

When user is on a chapter:
`www.domainname.com/course/chapter`

When a user is on a lesson: `www.domainname.com/course/chapter/lesson`

While looking in the WordPress Codex, I found the the [Rewrite API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API) and [WP_Rewrite()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Rewrite), I'm a little lost and i do not know where to begin.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [This](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule#Example) should get you started in the right direction. Try it and don't forget to flush your rewrite rules. Then, if you still need help, post back with details about what you tried and the specific issues you're experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that if you have lessons that are in multiple chapters you will create duplicate content.

If you want an easy way to connect these post types you can use a free plugin called Post Connector: http://wordpress.org/plugins/post-connector/